# Distributive sublattices of geometric modular lattices

Tags: reference-request, lattice-orders, matroids

I found a copy of *Lattice Theory* (by Birkhoff) in a dusty corner of our library. I just picked it up for fun and seems really interesting. I was mainly interested in geometric modular lattices.

My question is:

> Is there a bound on the size of largest distributive sublattice of a modular geometric lattice?

Additionally, I would like to know how to find good books, lecture notes on lattice theory. I would welcome any suggestions about the order of reading it too.

Thanks,

Comment: Incidentally someone posted a suggestions about books on lattices [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/166381/), although that question is about a different type of lattices. BTW I think it would be better ask these two things as separate questions - one about the bound and one about the book recommendations.

Comment: You can find J. B. Nation's Notes on lattice theory at this website: http://bigcheese.math.sc.edu/~mcnulty/alglatvar/

Comment: I've posted a [follow-up question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180578/introductory-text-for-lattice-theory) which only asks about recommendation for texts on lattice theory (=the last part of your question).

Answer (score 4):

The largest distributive lattice of rank $n$ has $2^n$ elements, so the largest distributive sublattice of *any* lattice of rank $n$ has size at most $2^n$. For *any* geometric lattice of rank $n$ this bound can be achieved by taking the sublattice generated by $n$ atoms forming a basis for the underlying matroid.

Answer (score 1):

Richard Stanley's book *Enumerative Combinatorics* is highly recommended.