# A book useful to learn lattices (discrete groups)

Tags: reference-request, integer-lattices, book-recommendation

Does anyone know a good book about lattices (as subgroups of a vector space $V$)?

Comment: In what context and for what purpose?

Comment: substantially an introduction to this interesting argument.

Comment: To what interesting argument?

Comment: The interesting argument is "Lattices" (I'm sorry for my unclear and stupid comment). I know that lattices are closely related to  "solid geometry" and I'm courious.

Answer (score 3):

[These notes of mine on geometry of numbers](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/geometryofnumbers.pdf) begin with a section on lattices in Euclidean space.  However they are a work in progress and certainly not yet fully satisfactory.  Of the references I myself have been consulting for this material, the one I have found most helpful with regard to basic material on lattices is [C.L. Siegel's *Lectures on the Geometry of Numbers*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Lectures_on_the_Geometry_of_Numbers.html?id=VA2W-dl78UYC).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

Roman,Steven: "Lattices and Ordered Sets", Springer

Blyth, T.S.: "Lattices and Ordered Algebraic Structures" , Springer

Roggenkamp, Klaus - Huber-Dyson, Verena : "Lattices over Orders" , Springer

Comment: these are books about lattices in this sense: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order) .

I need a book about:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)

Comment: DonAntonio, perhaps you could move your answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180578/introductory-text-for-lattice-theory), which is about this kind of lattices.