# Recommendation for Order Theory texts

Tags: reference-request, order-theory

Order Theory, Lattice Theory, or any directly relatable subject is not taught at my university, and quick searches don't give much clue into good textbooks for the subjects.

My question is: what are some good modern, introductory textbooks for order theory?

I have seen several questions regarding textbook recommendations for lattice theory ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180578/introductory-text-for-lattice-theory) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14341/good-lattice-theory-books)).  However, I was wanting something that dealt with both lattices and other orders (partial orders, preorders, etc) more generally.  It may be that there isn't much to say about these more general orders when they aren't lattices, but I wouldn't know any better.

Comment: I am late here, but maybe this will help: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-51495-1 It focuses on preferences in Economics, but preferences are usually thought of as orderings so it covers stuff that might be relevant to you too

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the theory of linear, or total orders, I suggest Rosenstein's *Linear Orderings*.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I knew, but since you have references for lattice theory, here's one for everything but lattice theory: Ok, [Real Analysis with Economics Applications](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=pYJmnnnA1dkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ok%20real%20analysis%20economic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=45o_Vdj5G-LCmQX4ioDYAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ok%20real%20analysis%20economic&f=false). Start with Ch. B sec. 4. In general, there's a lot of material in economics about preorders as preferences are typically taken to be preorders.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think this really covers the material I'm interested in.  Judging from the contents, there doesn't seem to be much more than one would learn from a course in Set Theory or Real Analysis, while I'm looking for something that expands on these significantly.

Comment: Did you consider Schroder, Ordered Sets? I haven't read it, but it looks pretty good (I am also looking for things in this area). Harzheim, Ordered Sets looks comparable but more advanced. Incidentally, some of the material on representations of preorders (especially on sets of probability measures) in economics is embedded in more advanced functional analysis, but is perhaps not what you're looking for.

Comment: From what I understand, Schroeder's text is quite well-known, being one of the "original" works on it (so far as introductory texts are concerned).  I've skimmed it and found it nice.  But other's that I've looked at (sadly I don't recall who the authors were) were largely comparable.  I suppose I am (or at least was) looking for a more theoretical-oriented text with some application towards universal algebra.