# Best simple textbook on lattice theory

Tags: book-recommendation, lattice-orders

What is a good book on lattice theory that is not complicated and can be used as an introduction to the subject (even long from the very basics to more advanced material)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Introductory text for lattice theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180578/introductory-text-for-lattice-theory)

Comment: @Äres no really since I have most of those books.. but ok